# Ignoring a ProtoRPC message field via Cloud Endpoints

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I've been working on an AppEngine-based project and I wanted to know if it's possible to ignore a ProtoRPC message field.

With the Java SDK, you can use `@ApiResourceProperty` to ignore a property (this means it's not contained within the response returned to the browser). However, I have not come across a way of doing this using the Python SDK.

Is there anything like this in the Python SDK?

Thanks, Adil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, unfortunately not (at least not to my knowledge).

Two possible solutions depending on your use-case.

1. Set field values to `None` before returning the message in your method. That way they will be skipped/not included in the JSON response.
2. If your messages are hooked up to datastore models you can use the [endpoints-proto-datastore](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-proto-datastore) library which allows you to use your ndb models directly in your API methods. Additionally it allows for `request_fields` and `response_fields` parameters in the method decorator which will limit the request or response to the specified subset of message/model fields. (internally it creates the necessary message classes for you)